# Content isn't loading in scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've created a dynamic scroll that worked in jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/9zXL5/39/

```
var movelist = document.getElementById('movelist');

function yHandler() {
    var contentHeight = movelist.scrollHeight;
    var yOffset = movelist.clientHeight;
    var y = yOffset + movelist.scrollTop;
    if (y >= contentHeight) {
        movelist.innerHTML += '<div class ="newData">yooooo</div>';
    }
}


movelist.onscroll = yHandler;​
```

but it had uncaught errors such as yHandler not being defined. So I fixed the errors by  placing var movielist=.. and movielist.onscroll = yHandler; inside my $(document).ready. The errors are gone, but now content won't load when my scroll hits the bottom as seen --> http://jsfiddle.net/9zXL5/40/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var movelist = document.getElementById('movelist');

    movelist.onscroll = yHandler;
});

function  yHandler (){

        var contentHeight = movelist.scrollHeight;

        var yOffset = movelist.clientHeight;

        var y = yOffset + movelist.scrollTop;

        if(y >= contentHeight){

            movelist.innerHTML += '<div class ="newData">hey look at me</div>';

        });
    }
}
```

and I cannot figure out why. I would really appreciate it if someone explained to me why this is so.

Comment: try `var yHandler = function() {` instead of `function yHandler (){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors in your fiddle:

1. You where not loading jQuery
2. You had several syntax errors

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zXL5/42/

It helps if you use a console (chrome/devtools or FF/firebug) to spot the errors and correct them. In your case, you had closing parentheses and brackets here:

```
        movelist.innerHTML += '<div class ="newData">hey look at me</div>';
    }); // <-- remove the );
} // <-- remove this line
```

Comment: Thank you, I use chrome's debugger and with this updated code I still don't get content loaded when I scroll to the bottom of my div when on my browser. Your thoughts?

Comment: Yes it does, look at the example fiddle. It’s just the positioning of the new text that is wrong. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9zXL5/43/

Comment: Sorry miscommunication, I'm saying on my localhost its static.

Answer (score 0):

You had a number of JavaScript syntax errors in that jsFiddle, caused by:

1. not loading jQuery,
2. having an unnecessary bracket and semi-colon (`);`) after your function declaration and having an additional, unmatched closing curly-brace (`}`) also after that function declaration.

If you haven't already I'd highly suggest you install, or start using, a JavaScript debugger. If you use Firefox, I'd personally suggest using Firebug. In Internet Explorer and Chrome the built-in developer tools can be accessed using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key.

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/9zXL5/41/).

Comment: Yea, thanks for that glance over. Still, I use chrome's debugger and even with this updated code content doesn't load in my browser and I have no errors @AnthonyGrist

Comment: @Octavius The first few are displayed *beside* the `<li>` elements, for reasons I couldn't immediately pinpoint (though I'll admit not looking particularly hard at it). You'll have to scroll to the bottom a few times before they start being added to the end.

Comment: No, I'm saying my scroll is static on my main browser. Why would the code be working on jsfiddle but not on my browser?

Comment: @Octavius Because your code is not the same as the one in jsFiddle. Stackoverflow cannot help you debug your site, only with specific problems that you post here.